# How do I do a function callback in Azure Functions on a function imported from a node module?

Tags: node.js, azure

I have spent hours over the last few days trying to figure out how to do a callback to get data out of a function I am importing from a node module and use it with context.res in an azure function.

I don't understand callbacks well enough to get my head around this, or I am completely off base.

```js
module.exports = function (context, req) {

var QuickBooks = require('node-quickbooks')
var qboAuth = require('./config')
var consumerKey = qboAuth.consumerKey
var consumerSecret = qboAuth.consumerSecret
var oauthToken = qboAuth.token
var oauthTokenSecret = qboAuth.tokenSecret
var realmId = qboAuth.realmId

    var qbo = new QuickBooks(consumerKey,
                         consumerSecret,
                         oauthToken,
                         oauthTokenSecret,
                         realmId,
                         false, // use the sandbox?
                         true); // enable debugging?
                
    
    qbo.getAccount(req.query.id, function(err, account) {
            context.log(account)
            
    } );
    
context.res = {
    body: account
}
     

context.done()
}
```

So the context.log(account) in the qbo.getAccount() function outputs fine, however through which ever means I use I cannot get this to output to context.res = {}.

I think this is complicated by running in the Azure Function sandbox, but I am not sure.

Is someone able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Dion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `getAccount()` should be an asynchronous function, you can move the assignment and complete function of Azure Function into the callback expression. E.G.

```
qbo.getAccount(req.query.id, function(err, account) {
    context.log(account);
    context.res = {
        body: account
    }
    context.done() 
    } 
);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Gary, that worked!

I had done that earlier and it hadn't worked, but I found just now one of my input variables had a typo since I was a bit more certain about the concept. Thanks again